# Weird Timeout problems on .Net module WebRequests

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, timeout, dotnet-httpclient

I've got the following issue:
I'm working on a .Net module which sends requests every ~500ms to a server situated in the same region as the IIS server.
Most of these requests (about 99%) take about 1~3ms to be treated. However, some of these requests are timing out (I've set the `WebRequest.Timeout` to 150ms, it is important).

There is two weird things:

- First the timeout requests would take about ~180ms to execute if I set the timeout to infinite, which is weird as the other requests are quick as lightning
- When catching the WebException resulting, I measure ~350ms between the moment I call `WebRequest.GetResponse()` and the moment the exception is catched whereas I've set the `WebRequet.Timeout` to 150ms. This gap of performance really is a problem for us and I don't understand why it is happening

This is the legacy code I'm working on:

```
ApiResult IApiService.Request(IConnectorRequest request)
{
    long timestamp = 0;
    DebugStream debug = null;

    try
    {
        var dictionary = CollectData(request);

        //TODO:May be include some ServicePoint information.
        //APIConnectionState=Reused

        // Sending request to the API //////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        var http = CreateRequest();

        Stream stream;
        using (stream = http.GetRequestStream())
        {
            if (_Log.IsDebug)
            {
                stream = debug = new DebugStream(stream, _Encoding);
            }

            dictionary.WriteForm(stream, _Encoding);
        }

        if (debug != null)
        {
            _Log.Debug("WebRequestApiService.Request({0:N}): {1}", request.Id, debug.Data);
        }

        // Start request and fix timestamp before execution.
        timestamp = Stopwatch.GetTimestamp();
        var response = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        // (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - timestamp) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond => ~2ms

        if (response == null)
        {
            const string message = "Response is not HttpWebResponse";
            _Log.Warning("WebRequestApiService.Request({0:N}): {1}", request.Id, message);

            return ApiResult.Failure(message);
        }
        response.GetRequestHeaders();
        return new ApiResult()
        {
            StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
            Description = response.StatusDescription,
            DataDomeStatus = response.GetStatusHeader(),
            Headers = response.GetHeaders()
        };
    }
    catch (WebException we)
    {
        var errorMessage = string.Empty;
        var response = we.Response as HttpWebResponse;
        Exception e;

        if (response != null)
        {
            errorMessage = response.GetText(out e);

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Forbidden)
            {
                return new ApiResult()
                {
                    StatusCode = (int)response.StatusCode,
                    Description = response.StatusDescription,
                    DataDomeStatus = response.GetStatusHeader(),
                    Headers = response.GetHeaders(),
                    Content = errorMessage
                };
            }

            if (errorMessage == null)
            {
                _Log.Warning("WebRequestApiService.Request({0}): Problem getting response {1}", request.Id, e);
            }
        }

        // (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - timestamp) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond => ~350ms
        _Log.Warning(
            "WebRequestApiService.Request({0}): Message={1}\nTimeout={2}\nError=\n{3}\n\nRequest=\n{4}\n\nAPI=\n{5}\n",
            request.Id,
            errorMessage,
            (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - timestamp) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond,
            we,
            request.Dump(),
            debug != null ? debug.Data : "NULL"
        );

        return ApiResult.Failure(errorMessage);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _Log.Warning(
            "WebRequestApiService.Request({0}): Timeout={1}\nError=\n{2}\n\nRequest=\n{3}\n\nAPI=\n{4}\n",
            request.Id,
            (Stopwatch.GetTimestamp() - timestamp) / TimeSpan.TicksPerMillisecond,
            e,
            request.Dump(),
            debug != null ? debug.Data : "NULL"
        );

        return ApiResult.Failure(e.Message);
    }
}
```

And this is the method used to create our HttpWebRequest:

```
private HttpWebRequest CreateRequest()
{
    var http = WebRequest.Create(_uri) as HttpWebRequest;

    if (http == null)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    // Disable proxy (if node proxy configuration in config file). Otherwise the first
    // request will be slowed down due the proxy auto-detection.
    if (_noProxy)
    {
        http.Proxy = null;
    }

    // Configure timeout. 150ms in our case
    http.Timeout = _timeout;

    // Force connection to be keep-alive.
    http.KeepAlive = true;

    // Disable caching.
    http.CachePolicy = _cachePolicy;

    // Basic request fields
    http.Method = "POST";
    http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    http.UserAgent = null;

    // If auto redirect is allowed, then we can't catch redirect response from API server.
    http.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    return http;
}
```

Does someone knows the behavior of WebRequest and why it can have some heavy slowdowns as I am experiencing? And why setting timeout to 150ms causes the exception to be catched at 350ms (which is a bad performance heavy problem for us)?

I'd really like some help from someone more experienced in C# and .Net because I'm new to this world and have customer requests constraints

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely DNS query related. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) for `Timeout` states:

> A Domain Name System (DNS) query may take up to 15 seconds to return
>   or time out. If your request contains a host name that requires
>   resolution and you set Timeout to a value less than 15 seconds, it may
>   take 15 seconds or more before a WebException is thrown to indicate a
>   timeout on your request.

Comment: I don't think it is DNS lookup related. I've tried to verify your idea, sniffing traffic for DNS lookup from my .Net application, the result is that over 10minutes and 1000 requests, only 4 DNS lookup have been made and 50 timeouts happened. Also the date of the timeouts and those from DNS lookup doesn't match :(